# Class running on localhost but doesn't work in CentOS

Tags: php, centos, composer-php

I created a project and publish it with packagist. [github](https://github.com/gloireTR/Anidb) -  [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/gloire/anidb).
And I installed the package using composer.
After that I tested on localhost with codes below and it worked smoothly

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$test = new \AniDB\Anime\Anime();
```

But I came across this error while testing on CentOS.

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AniDB\Anime\Anime' not found in /var/www/html/bot_interface.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/bot_interface.php on line 8**

Version of composer is the same as well as localhost and the server: Composer version 2.0.0-RC1 2020-09-10 15:39:45

I think this problem is caused by Centos? (CentOS 8.2 x64 - DigitalOcean)

Note: Now I install it to Debian too and it gave the same error

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Are you relly sure that this class exists on the server?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, I'm sure. I copied the codes that working on localhost. The result hasn't changed.